# How to reach stable selenium tests

Tags: asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui

I have a web application built using **ASP.NET Core and Kendo UI controls**, and I have developed 85 **Selenium** tests for this application, which are divided into classes using the Nunit test framework.
During development, I have considered the following points:

1. Implementation of the Page Object Design Pattern.
2. Usage of [OnTimeSetup] for each module, ensuring that the browser runs at the beginning of each module tests and closes at the end of each module tests.
3. I have set an implicit wait for 1 minute, and
4. Implemented explicit wait when necessary.

Despite these efforts, I still encounter random test failures during each run for different reasons. I'm unsure about the steps to take to achieve stable Selenium tests. Any suggestions or recommendations?